# Retrieve and Edit Contact Marketing List Subscribed using Webservice Endpoint Optiomization Cannot be Performed

Tags: acumatica

I am using my own custom webservice endpoint to access the Contacts.  I also want to get the list of marketing lists the contact is associated too and update the subscribed field.

But when I try expand the Marketing Lists details the API responds with this Optiomization cannot be performed error?  Message below

"message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Optimization cannot be performed.The following fields cause the error:\r\nMarketingLists.Subscribed: View Subscriptions has BQL delegate\r\nMarketingLists.MarketingListID: View Subscriptions has BQL delegate\r\nMarketingLists.ContactID: View Subscriptions has BQL delegate\r\n",

I get the same error when using the Default endpoint as well.

Also when trying to go the other way and get the marketing lists and expand the list members I also get the same similar message?

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it only works by retrieving one contact at a time.  Not by getting all Contacts at once.

Comment: Yes that's exact and by design. The issue is that the endpoint of the web service call uses a data view delegate to return the records. This can introduce performance issues so the system denies the request. The solution to this error is to retrieve records one by one and/or to omit the expand details parameter. Data view delegate reference: https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=8169bc20-c1de-4160-b687-54c24ea0419d